# Is it possible to direct the linker on where to put the section header content?

Tags: linker, linker-scripts

I have a linker script to order the sections in a particular order. But, I wanted to know if I can direct the linker to place the offset of section header table(e_shoff), before the offset of .shstrtab. The below output of readelf -h may show that e_shoff is placed before .shstrtab. But that not true for all binutils version and new linkers.

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4003d0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4912 (bytes into file)    <<< e_shoff
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         36
  Section header string table index: 33
```

Comment: Anyone please confirm if its possible?